# Can someone explain what is the difference VMware vCenter and VMware vSphere to me?

Tags: virtualization, esxi, vmware-server, vcenter

We are currently looking to implement a Geo Spatial Infrastructure (see below) that will include a number of servers and we are planning to run each server on a different virtual machine. At the very early stage we will be using two physical servers (one as a replica of the other)

I am a newbie to the virtualization world but from the Basic research that I have done and from the basic consultancies that I have done with local companies, I have come across the terms VMware vSphere,VMware vCenter and VMware SRM (vCenter Site Recovery Manager)? Can anyone explain the differences between them? Why would I need two vCenters and six Vspheres? I understand there is a virtualization OS, a virtualization management server and virtualization client but which is which and what is necessary and what is not.

Thanks!

[image: GeoSDI Infrastructure]

Comment: The folks proposing the solution should be able to explain the various components in detail.

Answer (score 3):

vCenter Server is the product that manages your physical VMware ESXi hosts. The ESXi hosts are the hypervisors that run your VMs. The vCenter Server will manage the hosts and the VMs on them. It will enable features like VMotion etc.

vCenter Site Recovery Manager will help you failover your VMs to a second datacenter if your first datacenter fails and you lose access to your ESXi hosts and vCenter. You will have downtime.